# Set timeout for callout mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 ESB 4.6.0 and in a specific moment, need to make a blocking call to an external web service. For that, I'm using the callout mediator:

```
<callout serviceURL="http://localhost:9773/services/OrderService" action="urn:mediate">
    <source xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xpath="s11:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1]"/>
    <target xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xpath="s11:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1]"/>
</callout>
```

The problem is, sometimes, this service may take about 100 seconds to complete and respond, but the callout throws an timeout error in 30 seconds.

What I want to know is: How to increase this timeout?

**EDIT**

Changing `synapse.global_timeout_interval` to 120000 has no effect to callout mediator. The timeout keep occurring in 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

when you set value to a value greater than 120 seconds we need to edit 'synapse.global_timeout_interval' value in synapse.properties file located in repository/conf/

or you can set timeout for end point as wel

```
<timeout> 
               <duration>1000</duration> 
               <responseAction>discard</responseAction> 
</timeout>
```

for more details: https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Endpoint+Error+Handling

Comment: Thanks for answer Dakshika. There's no way to set the timeout only for a specific mediator in a specific proxy?

Comment: check my previous answer, i did some changes on it

Comment: But this xml section is not applicable for the callout mediator.

Comment: The `synapse.global_timeout_interval` has already setted to 120000 but seems like it's not being respected by the callout mediator.

Comment: It seems http socket timeout is always 60 seconds..How to change this value? I want 10 seconds for every kind of timeout..how to set this? Setting 10 seconds on the endpoint not work for host unreachable. Also I want that after 10 seconds, the fault should be triggered so that I can send back a response..Why this seems so complicated? It seems a basic thing for an esb